# How to check the column value of all parent record of a child in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, parent, hierarchical-data

Lets say we have a single table with 3 columns: **ID**, **PARENT_ID** and **VALUE**.

We have for example 8 records:

```
ID PARENT_ID VALUE
A  NULL      1
B  A         1
C  B         0
D  C         1
E  D         1
F  E         1
G  F         1
H  G         0
```

How can we check using a SQL query or stored procedure (for MySQL preferably) if any of the parent record for record with ID "G" has a value of 0?  If a parent from the chain has 0 for VALUE, there is no need to check further back.

This has to work by taking any child ID and look at the entire chain of its parents **before** that child.  Some child could have no parents or could also have a chain of parents and a parent record can have 0 or many child records.

In this example, the search would end at record with ID "C" (ie: return that ID is fine) since it is the parent record of the chain of parents (for G) that is 0 for VALUE.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What version of MySQL? If you want the entire parent chain you need a recursive CTE, which is only available in 8.x.

Comment: See https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Sure, I have the latest version of MySQL.  Let me check out that link.

Comment: The mikehillyer solution is not the MySQL 8 recursive CTE solution, it's for folks who _don't_ have MySQL 8 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a MySQL 8.0 recursive CTE query that does what you describe, traverse the ancestors of 'G' and return those that have a value = 0:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select * from mytable where id = 'G'
  union all
  select t.* from cte join mytable t on t.id = cte.parent_id
) select * from cte where value = 0;

+------+-----------+-------+
| id   | parent_id | value |
+------+-----------+-------+
| C    | B         |     0 |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html for more about recursive CTE queries.